# Uniform convergent sequence of functions without convergence maxima

Tags: analysis

I am looking for a sequence of functions $f_n$ that converge uniformly to some function $f$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\max \{f_n(x)\}\neq\max\{ f(x)\}$. My gut feeling tells me I have to use something like $\sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}<\sup\{f(x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\}$, but I can't think of any example for the life of me. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that such an example even exists? Let me try a proof:
Since $f_n$ converges uniformely we have for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ an $n_0(\epsilon)$ such that for every $n\geq n_0$ and every $x$ we have
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon.$$
Hence we also have for every $x$ and $n\geq n_0$
$$f_n(x) \leq f(x) + \epsilon,$$
$$f(x) \leq f_n(x) + \epsilon.$$
By first going to the supremum over $x$ on the right hand side, we get
$$\sup\{f_n(x)\} \leq \sup\{f(x)\} + \epsilon $$
$$\sup\{f(x)\} \leq \sup\{f_n(x)\} + \epsilon$$
This yields for every $n\geq n_0$
$$|\sup\{f_n(x)\}-\sup\{f(x)\}|\leq \epsilon,$$
hence $\sup\{f_n(x)\}\rightarrow\sup\{f(x)\}$.

Maybe the question is more directed at the attainment of the supremum? Or maybe the word 'local' is missing, i.e. I think the result is false for local uniform convergence.